# Spring Boot and AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want make some spring boot app. I've already created spring boot project, but I have a problem. My controller look like:

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/home",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String homepage(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

But all what i see is not index.html, but only a word "index".
Therefore I want use angular.

```
angular.module('mvcApp', [])
    .constant('MODULE_NAME', "index")
    .config(['$routeSegmentProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($routeSegmentProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $routeSegmentProvider
            .when('/', 'index')
            .when('/index', 'index')
            .when('/configuration', 'configuration')

        $routeSegmentProvider.segment('index', {
            templateUrl: 'HTML/index.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);
```

and controller:

```
angular.module('mvcApp').controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.hello = "Hello from AngularJS";

}]);
```

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello!</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="mvcApp" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">

Greeting page.
{{hello}}

</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work, I see only error on my localhost.

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Sep 04 15:33:41 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

How I can make this angular controller works and return properly views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be class like that:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/HTML/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your setup should work if you actually bind the `/index` as the request mapping, and not `/home`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homepage(){
    return "index";
}
```

Assuming you don't have some random `@EnableWebMvc` annotated config somewhere that kills your initial boot setup.

Comment: it works, but it shows me only word "index". Controller don't search for index.html. I want use angular, and this provider:  $routeSegmentProvider
            .when('/', 'index')
            .when('/index', 'index')

Comment: Then replace `@RestController` with `@Controller`

Comment: I guess you should use @RequestMapping() before class name.

Answer (score 1):

@EpicPandaForce has the correct answer. You want to use `@Controller`, not `@RestController`. `@RestController` is a meta-annotation with `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`. `@Controller` will search through the registered `ViewResolver`s, whereas `@RestController` will not.

Answer (score 0):

When you use @RestController spring does not use the view resolver. So that you should change @RestController to @Controller